# All permutations of form options

Tags: c#, .net, permutation

I'm trying to test a form by submitting a combination of all values to see if it breaks. These are ComboBoxes that I have stored in an ExtraField class

```
public class ExtraField
{
    public String Name = ""; //name of form key
    public Dictionary<String, String> Options = new Dictionary<String, String>(); //Format: OptionText, Value
}
```

I have generated a list of these fields

```
List<ExtraField> efList = new List<ExtraField>();
```

I was thinking all possible combinations of these fields could be added to a string list that I can parse (I was thinking name=opt|name=opt|name=opt). I've provided an example of what would work below (where ExtraField list Count==3):

```
        List<ExtraField> efList = new List<ExtraField>();
        ExtraField f1 = new ExtraField();
        f1.Name = "name1";
        f1.Options.Add("text", "option1");
        f1.Options.Add("text2", "option2");
        f1.Options.Add("text3", "option3");
        efList.Add(f1);
        ExtraField f2 = new ExtraField();
        f2.Name = "name2";
        f2.Options.Add("text", "option1");
        f2.Options.Add("text2", "option2");
        f2.Options.Add("text3", "option3");
        f2.Options.Add("text4", "option4");
        efList.Add(f2);
        ExtraField f3 = new ExtraField();
        f3.Name = "name3";
        f3.Options.Add("text2", "option1");
        f3.Options.Add("text3", "option2");
        f3.Options.Add("text4", "option3");
        f3.Options.Add("text5", "option4");
        f3.Options.Add("text6", "option5");
        efList.Add(f3);
```

Should produce

```
name1=option1|name2=option1|name3=option1
name1=option1|name2=option1|name3=option2
name1=option1|name2=option1|name3=option3
name1=option1|name2=option1|name3=option4
name1=option1|name2=option1|name3=option5
name1=option1|name2=option2|name3=option1
name1=option1|name2=option2|name3=option2
name1=option1|name2=option2|name3=option3
name1=option1|name2=option2|name3=option4
name1=option1|name2=option2|name3=option5
name1=option1|name2=option3|name3=option1
name1=option1|name2=option3|name3=option2
name1=option1|name2=option3|name3=option3
name1=option1|name2=option3|name3=option4
name1=option1|name2=option3|name3=option5
name1=option1|name2=option4|name3=option1
name1=option1|name2=option4|name3=option2
name1=option1|name2=option4|name3=option3
name1=option1|name2=option4|name3=option4
name1=option1|name2=option4|name3=option5
name1=option2|name2=option1|name3=option1
...etc
```

All ExtraFields in the list need to have a value and I need all permutations in one format or another. It's a big list with a lot of permutations otherwise I'd do it by hand.

Comment: Is your question how to generate a text file like the example you provided?

Comment: A list of strings with each string containing values for each field name*. Unless there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

So I managed to do it recursively. I haven't done this since college :D

Here's the whole class:
https://gist.github.com/Rastamas/8070ae7e1471d2183451a17bcf061376

**PREVIOUS ANSWER BELOW**

This goes through your list and adds the strings to a `StringBuilder` in the format you showed

```
foreach (var item in efList)
{
    foreach (var option in item.Options)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}|", item.Name, option.Value));
    }
    stringBuilder.Remove(stringBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine();
}
```

Then you can just use `stringBuilder.ToString()` to get the whole list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I need it done a bit differently, though. I updated my question with example input and example desired output

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it... But I'm not proud of it. I'm sure there is a better way of doing it recursively. Hopefully this helps someone.

```
    public List<String> GetFormPermutations(List<ExtraField> inList)
    {
        List<String> retList = new List<String>();

        int[] listIndexes = new int[inList.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < listIndexes.Length; i++)
            listIndexes[i] = 0;

        while (listIndexes[inList.Count-1] < inList.ElementAt(inList.Count-1).Options.Count)
        {
            String cString = "";
            //after this loop is complete. a line is done.
            for (int i = 0; i < inList.Count; i++) {
                String key = inList.ElementAt(i).Name;
                Dictionary<String, String> cOptions = inList.ElementAt(i).Options;
                String value = cOptions.ElementAt(listIndexes[i]).Value;
                cString += key + "=" + value;

                if (i < inList.Count - 1)
                    cString += "|";
            }
            retList.Add(cString);

            listIndexes[0]++;
            for(int i = 0; i < inList.Count -1; i++)
            {
                if (listIndexes[i] >= inList.ElementAt(i).Options.Count)
                {
                    listIndexes[i] = 0;
                    listIndexes[i + 1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return retList;
    }
```